# Need to know how hash key are handled in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on ruby rails project. I am using Rails 2.3.4 and ruby 1.8.7 . I have a model called User.

I have following code in initializer

```
$h =  {User => 'I am user' }
```

In the controller I have following code

```
$h[User]
```

First time when I do h[User] I get the right result. However if I refresh the page then I get nil value.

I think this is what is happening.

First time when User class is loaded then I get the right value. However when I refresh the page then this time controller returns nil value for $h[User].

Because rails unloads all the constants when page is refreshed so it seems a new User class is loaded. This User class is different from the User that was used as key in initializer.

I know using User class is a bad practice.  My question is can someone explain to me when User class is used as key then internally how ruby stores the key. Does ruby use object_id of User as the key? I

Comment: I particularly like this in your question: "I know using User class is a bad practice. My question is can someone explain to me when User class is used as key then internally how ruby stores the key." It shows how an accident lead to a quest for deeper understanding, and it also helps responders stay on-topic (rather than simply saying, "don't use User as a key.") Very well asked, Roger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Hash` calls the `hash` method on any objects used as a key.  And yes, your theory as to why your code isn't working is correct.

Try this in the Rails console:

```
User.hash # => 215678765 (or whatever)
reload! 
User.hash # => 215876673
```

Reloading the class changed the value returned by the `hash` method, meaning it is no longer the same key when used in a `Hash`.

Use `:user` or something else that will resolve to the same key every time.

Answer (score 0):

The [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000337) method is used on each object used as a key in a Hash.